# Posting image to twitter using php not working

Tags: php, twitter

Posting image to twitter using php not working . Please check my code.

```
<?
define( 'YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY' , '######################');
define( 'YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET' , '######################');

require ('../../twitt/tmhOAuth.php');
require ('../../twitt/tmhUtilities.php');

$tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuth(array(
         'consumer_key'    => "######################",
         'consumer_secret' => "######################",
         'user_token'      => "######################",
         'user_secret'     => "######################",
));

$image = 'Tulips.jpg';

$code = $tmhOAuth->request( 'POST','https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json',
   array(
        'media[]'  => "@{$image};",
        'status'   => 'message text written here',
   ),
    true, // use auth
    true  // multipart
);

if ($code == 200){
   tmhUtilities::pr(json_decode($tmhOAuth->response['response']));
}else{
   tmhUtilities::pr($tmhOAuth->response['response']);
}
print_r($code);
```

?>

It is not working. I always return 0. What is the issue in this code? Anyone please help me....

Comment: I guess you are trying https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1059, but the only difference I see is that you use `$image = 'Tulips.jpg';` and they include `./` in the image path which resolves to the current dir. Try `$image = './Tulips.jpg';`

Comment: Debug your code, check each value, check PHP error log.

Comment: @HugoDelsing i tried with that path. it's not working.

Comment: @Jocelyn The values are correct, the problem is with twitter posting.